# Why does this program create an output like this?

Tags: c++, arrays, output

Why does this program write 45, 125 and 300?
I know for 45 and 300, I'm more interested in a case sum1(arrD), where program writes 125.
I hope somebody will know.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    B(): b(bCounter++){}
    int b;
    static int bCounter;
};

int B::bCounter = 0;

class D : public B{
public:
    D() : d(bCounter){}
    int d;
};

const int N = 10;
B arrB[N];
D arrD[N];


int sum1(B* arr){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) s+=arr[i].b;
    return s;
}

int sum2 (D* arr){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) s+= arr[i].b + arr[i].d;
    return s;
}

int main(){
    cout<<" result is: "<<sum1(arrB)<<endl;
    cout<<" result is: "<<sum1(arrD)<<endl;
    cout<<" result is: "<<sum2(arrD)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The static arrays B `arrB[N]` and D `arrD[N]` seem to be causing the trouble here.

Comment: And what did happen when you debugged the application by using breakpoints and watch the values?

Comment: When I debug, it won't go to the constructor to let me see what are the values of b and d. 
But I figured out another way of debuging and B.b's are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, D.b's are 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 and D.d's are 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20. The result 125 is 10 + 11 + 11 + 12 + 12 + 13 + 13 + 14 + 14 + 15 but I don't know why these values.

Comment: Try not putting the constructor on one line, to help debugging.

Comment: do you have a typo? sum([10..19]) = 145

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays aren't polymorphic; you can pass a `D*` to a function expecting a `B*` only if it expects a single element.  (Try using `std::vector`, and you'll get a compile time error.)  The reason is simple: the pointer arithmetic needed to access the array elements is based on the static size of the pointed to element, so each time you do `i++` in the loop in `sum1`, and then index, the compiler calculates the address of your element as `arr + i * sizeof(B)` (at the machine level, where `arr` is a pure, untyped address).

Trying to do pointer arithmetic when the static type is not the same as the dynamic type is undefined behavior, so as far as the language is concerned, anything can happen.

And this is yet another reason *not* to use C style arrays.

Comment: Yeah. Great explanation. It makes sense - it sounds so easy when somebody like you tell in this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the arrays do not contain pointers to the objects but whole objects.
So when you use the D array via a pointer to the base class, (as James noted) the behaviour is undefined.

What in practice probably happens on most systems: The pointer-based loop only iterates over half the D objects, because a B object contains only one `int`, while the D objects contain two of them.

So the loop looks only at the first 5 D objects:

```
b / d
10/11
11/12
12/13
13/14
14/15
```

which sums up to the ominous 125.

Comment: Probably.  The behavior is undefined, and in fact, anything could happen.  If he added a virtual destructor to B (which is recommended if you're deriving), the results could (and probably would) be completely different.

Comment: Yes.  The real fun starts happening when there are virtual functions, and you call one in the loop.  (Of course, on most machines, just changing one of the data types to `double` will result in really strange results.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's incorrect to cast an array of D to an array of B. The stride isn't correct. This is why you see these repeats of values.

Answer (score 0):

Run following code , you'll know the reason

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    B(): b(bCounter++){
        cout<<"B called\n";
        }
    int b;
    static int bCounter;
};

int B::bCounter = 0;

class D : public B{
public:
    D() : d(bCounter){
        cout<<"D called\n";
        }
    int d;
};

const int N = 10;
B arrB[N];
D arrD[N];


int sum1(B* arr){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    { 
        cout<<arr[i].b<<"\n";
        s+=arr[i].b;
    }
    return s;
}

int sum2 (D* arr){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) s+= arr[i].b + arr[i].d;
    return s;
}

int main(){
    //cout<<" result is: "<<sum1(arrB)<<endl;
    cout<<" result is: "<<sum1(arrD)<<endl;
    //cout<<" result is: "<<sum2(arrD)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should provide the reason rather than saying "you'll know the reason".